# awk - do not check fields with \n symbol inside of ""

Tags: design-patterns, awk, newline, quotes

I have a db export .txt file. Elements situated in double quotes("Test_data1"). Separator between elements is tab symbol(\t). size more than 1Gb.

```
Example(this is 1 string):

"Test_data1"    "Test_data2"    "1s"    "452"   "Test
data643"    "
"   "4d"    "System"    "Institute"
```

issue: find and print strings with specific condition in the 2nd column

```
awk -F\"'\t'\" '$2 ~ /Test_data2/ {print $0}' input.txt >> sorted/result.txt
```

but how to exclude from this search new line symbol (\n) inside of double quotes ("")?

I can not use RS parameter, because we have a new line symbol inside of "" ("\n")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a specific case of the general CSV parsing problem. The general solution is provided by Lorance Stinson (google `Stinson awk CSV parser`) but IMHO the simplest way to deal with this specific issue is to convert newlines within double quotes to some other character, do whatever you want with the file in single-line-per-record format, then convert back, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
"Test_data1"    "Test_data2"    "1s"    "452"   "Test
data643"    "
"   "4d"    "System"    "Institute"
"Test_data3"    "Test_data4"    "2s"    "563"   "Test
data754"    "
"   "5d"    "Non System"    "Association"
```

To convert to single line:

```
$ awk -v FS= '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="\"") inQ=!inQ; ORS=(inQ?"♥":"\n") }1' file
"Test_data1"    "Test_data2"    "1s"    "452"   "Test♥data643"    "♥"   "4d"    "System"    "Institute"
"Test_data3"    "Test_data4"    "2s"    "563"   "Test♥data754"    "♥"   "5d"    "Non System"    "Association"
```

and to convert back is a simple `tr`:

```
$ awk -v FS= '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="\"") inQ=!inQ; ORS=(inQ?"♥":"\n") }1' file | tr '♥' '
\n'
"Test_data1"    "Test_data2"    "1s"    "452"   "Test
data643"    "
"   "4d"    "System"    "Institute"
"Test_data3"    "Test_data4"    "2s"    "563"   "Test
data754"    "
"   "5d"    "Non System"    "Association"
```

The above uses control-C as a replacement for the newline within quotes, pick whatever character you like (or string if you want to use awk or sed rather than tr to convert back to newlines).

Just insert the command to do whatever you want with your original file in between the awk and the tr, e.g. sort in reverse:

```
$ awk -v FS= '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="\"") inQ=!inQ; ORS=(inQ?"♥":"\n") }1' file | sort -r | tr '♥' '\n'
"Test_data3"    "Test_data4"    "2s"    "563"   "Test
data754"    "
"   "5d"    "Non System"    "Association"
"Test_data1"    "Test_data2"    "1s"    "452"   "Test
data643"    "
"   "4d"    "System"    "Institute"
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! this method is really working! Now I understand how to parse files like this!

Comment: in UTF-8 encoding symbol ^C is pasting after new line symbol (\n). how  does it(^C) paste instead of "\n"?

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what that question means. If control-C isn't working for you, pick some other character? If that doesn't work, post another question asking for help with that specifically as it's different from your original question.

Comment: I confused a little bit, because this script working perfectly for your example, but for my input file it doesn't work! Structures for both of files the same! And I can not reproduce this problem!

Comment: Maybe you created your input file on Windows and so it's been corrupted by trailing control-Ms? Maybe you did a copy/paste of my script that turned control-Cs into the character `^` followed by the character `C`? Without some concrete information on what is happening when you run the script, its just guesswork. Update your question or post a new question with a copy/paste of your input, the script, and the output including error messages.

Comment: Ed, thanks for your help! I provided an example of my input file and a result after applying awk command. Look at updated question, please.

Comment: Change the characters "^" and "C" to a "control-C" character. You may need to type control-v first to enter it. I just updated my answer to make sure it shows `♥` everywhere and not `^C`.

Comment: Oh! I found a solution. The problem was in end of line symbol. In my file it was the windows end of line symbol. I change it to UNIX end of line symbol and script started working correctly! Ed, thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: No problem. That was my other suggestion, that you look for those goofy control-Ms that windows adds.

Comment: It's better to change this part of sort command tr '♥' '\n' to smth like this: tr "^~|" "\n". Because in UNIX UTF-8 encoding no symbol '♥'. And combination '^C' is changing every '\n' to capital 'C' symbol. It may cause a lot of problems in future with parsing output file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **gawk** in available, you can try this:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FS = "\"\t\""; RS = "[^\t]\"\n"}; 
      $2 ~ /Test_data2/ {print $0 RT};' input.txt
```

**else** you can try this:

*file a.awk:*

```
BEGIN {RS="\t"; FS="\n"; rest = "";}

{    
    s = rest $0; i = 1; success = 0;

    while (1) 
    {   
        if (i == 2 && $1 ~ "f2") success = 1;    

        if ((NF == 2 && $0 ~ "\"\n\"") || (getline) <= 0)  
        {   
            rest = $2; 
            break;
        }   

        s = s RS $1; 
        i++;
    }   

    if (success) print s;
}
```

*run:* `awk -f a.awk input.txt`

Good luck.